# Error when try to load plugin in Gatsby Cloud

Tags: npm, hosting, gatsby-cloud

I'm getting a strange error in Gatsby Cloud when I try to host the website.This happened since I added code syntax highlighting. The weird thing is it works perfectly when I run it locally on localhost, but it fails when I build it using Gatsby Cloud. (Gatsby Cloud uses the github repo of my website)

The error message I'm getting:

```
There was a problem loading plugin /usr/src/app/www/node_modules/@gatsby-cloud-pkg/gatsby-plugin-preview/dist/index.js. Perhaps you need to install its package?
```

My `gatsby-config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    ...
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
            options: {},
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `software`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/software`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `post`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/post`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-image`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `GetMyIsland Portfolio`,
        short_name: `GetMyIsland Portfolio`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#000000`,
        theme_color: `#000000`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `src/images/icon/LogoTransparent.png`,
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

Like I said the error appeared after installing `prismjs` and `gatsby-remark-prismjs`.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can fix this error message, since I wasn't able to find anything on the internet. If you need more information please tell me I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove the plugin that's causing issue and also that plugin/pakage which you think is causing issue and re install them freshly